# Moment.js частота обновления информации

Tags: javascript, settimeout, momentjs

Библиотека [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) умеет выводить оставшееся время до даты:

```
var time = moment().add(2,'h');
setInterval(function(){
   console.log(moment().to(time)); //"Через 2 часа"
},1000);
```

Эта строка отображается где-нибудь на веб-странице, как узнать когда она измениться?
Только в ручную после каждого раза проверять сколько осталось и выполнять через это время:

```
var time = moment().add(10,'m');
moment().diff();
disp();
function disp(){
    console.log(moment().to(time));
    setTimeout(disp,get_time());
}
function get_time(){
    var diff = time.diff(moment(), 'm');
    if(diff > 60) return 3600000; //1 час
    else if(diff > 1) return 60000; //1 мин
    else return 10000; //10 сек
}
```

- Если больше часа - обновлять раз в час
- Если больше минуты - обновлять раз в минуту
- Если больше секунды - обновлять раз в секунду

Или есть более правильные и просты решения?

Comment: Не совсем ясно что вы хотите. Если больше секунды - то больше и часа соответсвенно. Просто обновляйте раз в секунду и все. Или уточните вопрос